# How to change state of modal from a different component in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I'm learning React and I'm stuck. I am using a TailwindUI modal and I want it to pop up when a product from the products component is clicked. How do I change the state of the modal from false to true when something is clicked in the products component. Just to clarify, the modal component is called in the products component but the initial stat of the modal is set to false.

```
import Modal from "./Modal";

const products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Organize Basic Set (Walnut)",
    price: "$149",
    rating: 5,
    reviewCount: 38,
    imageSrc:
      "https://tailwindui.com/img/ecommerce-images/category-page-05-image-card-01.jpg",
    imageAlt: "TODO",
    href: "#",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Organize Pen Holder",
    price: "$15",
    rating: 5,
    reviewCount: 18,
    imageSrc:
      "https://tailwindui.com/img/ecommerce-images/category-page-05-image-card-02.jpg",
    imageAlt: "TODO",
    href: "#",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Organize Sticky Note Holder",
    price: "$15",
    rating: 5,
    reviewCount: 14,
    imageSrc:
      "https://tailwindui.com/img/ecommerce-images/category-page-05-image-card-03.jpg",
    imageAlt: "TODO",
    href: "#",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Organize Phone Holder",
    price: "$15",
    rating: 4,
    reviewCount: 21,
    imageSrc:
      "https://tailwindui.com/img/ecommerce-images/category-page-05-image-card-04.jpg",
    imageAlt: "TODO",
    href: "#",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Organize Basic Set (Walnut)",
    price: "$149",
    rating: 5,
    reviewCount: 38,
    imageSrc:
      "https://tailwindui.com/img/ecommerce-images/category-page-05-image-card-01.jpg",
    imageAlt: "TODO",
    href: "#",
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "Organize Pen Holder",
    price: "$15",
    rating: 5,
    reviewCount: 18,
    imageSrc:
      "https://tailwindui.com/img/ecommerce-images/category-page-05-image-card-02.jpg",
    imageAlt: "TODO",
    href: "#",
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: "Organize Sticky Note Holder",
    price: "$15",
    rating: 5,
    reviewCount: 14,
    imageSrc:
      "https://tailwindui.com/img/ecommerce-images/category-page-05-image-card-03.jpg",
    imageAlt: "TODO",
    href: "#",
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: "Organize Phone Holder",
    price: "$15",
    rating: 4,
    reviewCount: 21,
    imageSrc:
      "https://tailwindui.com/img/ecommerce-images/category-page-05-image-card-04.jpg",
    imageAlt: "TODO",
    href: "#",
  },
  // More products...
];

function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(" ");
}

export default function Products() {
  return (
    <div className='bg-white' id='product-line'>
      <div className='max-w-7xl mx-auto overflow-hidden sm:px-6 lg:px-8'>
        <h2 className='sr-only'>Products</h2>
        <h1 className='text-3xl font-extrabold text-blue-800 mt-10 sm:mt-20 mb-1 ml-4'>
          Product Line
        </h1>

        <div className='-mx-px border-l border-gray-200 grid grid-cols-2 sm:mx-0 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4'>
          {products.map((product) => (
            <div
              key={product.id}
              className='group relative p-4 border-r border-b border-gray-200 sm:p-6'
            >
              <div className='rounded-lg overflow-hidden bg-gray-200 aspect-w-1 aspect-h-1 group-hover:opacity-75'>
                <img
                  src={product.imageSrc}
                  alt={product.imageAlt}
                  className='w-full h-full object-center object-cover'
                />
              </div>
              <div className='pt-10 pb-4 text-center'>
                <h3 className='text-sm font-medium text-gray-500'>
                  <a href={product.href}>
                    <span aria-hidden='true' className='absolute inset-0' />
                    {product.name}
                  </a>
                </h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
import { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import { Dialog, Transition } from "@headlessui/react";
import { CheckIcon } from "@heroicons/react/outline";

export default function Modal() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Transition.Root show={open} as={Fragment}>
      <Dialog
        as='div'
        className='fixed z-10 inset-0 overflow-y-auto'
        onClose={setOpen}
      >
        <div className='flex items-end justify-center min-h-screen pt-4 px-4 pb-20 text-center sm:block sm:p-0'>
          <Transition.Child
            as={Fragment}
            enter='ease-out duration-300'
            enterFrom='opacity-0'
            enterTo='opacity-100'
            leave='ease-in duration-200'
            leaveFrom='opacity-100'
            leaveTo='opacity-0'
          >
            <Dialog.Overlay className='fixed inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity' />
          </Transition.Child>

          {/* This element is to trick the browser into centering the modal contents. */}
          <span
            className='hidden sm:inline-block sm:align-middle sm:h-screen'
            aria-hidden='true'
          >
            &#8203;
          </span>
          <Transition.Child
            as={Fragment}
            enter='ease-out duration-300'
            enterFrom='opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95'
            enterTo='opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100'
            leave='ease-in duration-200'
            leaveFrom='opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100'
            leaveTo='opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95'
          >
            <div className='inline-block align-bottom bg-white rounded-lg px-4 pt-5 pb-4 text-left overflow-hidden shadow-xl transform transition-all sm:my-8 sm:align-middle sm:max-w-sm sm:w-full sm:p-6'>
              <div>
                <div className='mx-auto flex items-center justify-center h-12 w-12 rounded-full bg-green-100'>
                  <CheckIcon
                    className='h-6 w-6 text-green-600'
                    aria-hidden='true'
                  />
                </div>
                <div className='mt-3 text-center sm:mt-5'>
                  <Dialog.Title
                    as='h3'
                    className='text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900'
                  >
                    Payment successful
                  </Dialog.Title>
                  <div className='mt-2'>
                    <p className='text-sm text-gray-500'>
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                      Consequatur amet labore.
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className='mt-5 sm:mt-6'>
                <button
                  type='button'
                  className='inline-flex justify-center w-full rounded-md border border-transparent shadow-sm px-4 py-2 bg-indigo-600 text-base font-medium text-white hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:text-sm'
                  onClick={() => setOpen(false)}
                >
                  Go back to dashboard
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Transition.Child>
        </div>
      </Dialog>
    </Transition.Root>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `props`. You should manage the Modal's open state in `Products` and pass the value to `Modal` as a `prop` whenever a product is clicked. Add a `onClose` prop to `Modal` and create a function to call `setOpen(false)` in `Product` whenever the modal is closed.
Also, include `<Modal>` somewhere in `Product`'s `render()` method, otherwise you will never see it.

In `Products`, it would be something like this:

```
export default function Products() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  //...
  return (
    //...
    // somewhere in the code you set a onClick event to run setOpen(true)   
    <Modal open={open} onClose={() => setOpen(false)}>
    //...
  )
}
```

Then in `Modal`:

```
export default function Modal(props) {
  const {open, onClose} = props;

  return (
    <Transition.Root show={open} as={Fragment}>
    //...
       <button
          type='button'
          className='inline-flex justify-center w-full rounded-md border border-transparent shadow-sm px-4 py-2 bg-indigo-600 text-base font-medium text-white hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:text-sm'
          onClick={() => onClose(false)}
       >
    //...
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I just figured it out and then I saw your comment and you are absolutely correct. The other issue I was having for anyone else struggling is that I needed to wrap my setOpen in an arrow function.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it! yeah, the arrow function will allow you to not just set a handler for the event but also pass arguments to it when its called.

Comment: This will cause Products to rerender when the modal state changes.

Comment: @Alain1405 thanks for your comment, would you consider to add a new answer pointing out the problem and showing how to solve it? I think it would be better for future readers (and me). Thanks in advance!

Comment: @pazitos10 I wish I knew! I got here trying to figure out how to avoid rerendering on a page with a modal, when changing the modal status from the page. 
I suspect the only way is to store the modal open status on the modal component and change it from the page by means of a ref to the modal, but I did not get to try it yet.